# Should we use Rails routes or React routers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, url-routing

I am new with React and today I was working on react-routers. I am not clear which routes to use. My choices are Rails routing or React router. What are the difference between these?

Answer (score 1):

React should be used for rendering and Rails should be used for the API.
Each react app should have its own server-rendered path, with calls to a rails API on the backend. The API should definitely be routed with rails, but only pass back the data you need to the react app. Rails 5 has ApiController you can use for your controller superclass.
TL;DR - React is frontend, rails API on the backend.

Also, you should really determine if you need something so heavyweight on the backend. Some lighter ruby alternatives are Sinatra and Padrino.

Answer (score 0):

You can use them for both server side and client side. If you are fully MEAN stack then you can use that. If you are in Rails stack then it's not possible.

Comment: I have many seperate pages in Rails application so what you suggest to use Rails routing or React routing ?

Comment: That means you are using Rails stack for backend. Use react route at client side routing.